# How to avoid large line spacing between variable label and factor levels in flextable (based on tbl_summary) saved to Word

Tags: r

I have created a table using tbl_summary and flextable to be saved to Word. I have used flextable as an intermediate step to set the font size and line spacing. In the Word document that is created, there are nasty big gaps between the variable labels and factor levels of the two categorical variables (Sex, Educational attainment). I mean the gap between "Sex" and "Female" (too far away from each other) and the gap between "Educational attainment" and "Higher" (also too far away from each other).

How can I avoid these large gaps? I want all the lines (rows) of the table to have the same line spacing.

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
sex <- factor(c("Male","Female","Female","Male","Female","Male","Female","Female","Female","Female","Male","Female","Female","Male","Male","Male","Female","Female","Female","Female"))
age <- c(21,25,32,24,63,52,75,24,65,95,58,36,46,58,65,19,47,48,33,54)
education <- factor(c("Primary","Secondary","Secondary","Higher","Secondary","Primary","Higher","Secondary","Secondary","Higher","Secondary","Secondary","Higher","Secondary","Secondary","Primary","Secondary","Higher","Secondary","Secondary"))
df1 <- data.frame(id,sex,age,education)

table <- df1 %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  tbl_summary(statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                               all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
              label = list(sex ~ "Sex",
                           age ~ "Age (years)",
                           education ~ "Educational attainment")) %>% 
  modify_footnote(
    all_stat_cols() ~ "Statistics presented:  \nn (%) for continuous variables;  \nMean (SD) for categorical variables"
  ) %>% 
  as_flex_table() %>% 
  fontsize(size = 8, part = "all") %>% 
  line_spacing(i = 1, space = 0.5, part = "body")

table

save_as_docx(
  "Table: Descriptive statistics" = table,
  path = "Table.docx")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the padding Default value.

```r
# set the padding in the defaults before your table pipe 

set_flextable_defaults(
  font.size = 8,
  padding=2,
  line_spacing = 1
)
```

Comment: it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The key here is to add `valign(valign = "center", part = "all")`. As default, it seems that tbl_summary (or it might be due to flextable, I'm not sure) vertically aligns the variable labels to the top of the row while the factor levels are vertically centered. That's why there are these large vertical gaps that I mentioned in my original questions. The difference after adding `valign(valign = "center", part = "all")` is subtle, but in my opinion makes the table look better. By the way, using padding.top and padding.bottom instead of line_spacing helps to make the table even more compact (but without `valign(valign = "center", part = "all")` the table would still look sub-optimal.

Without `valign(valign = "center", part = "all")`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
library(flextable)

id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
sex <- factor(c("Male","Female","Female","Male","Female","Male","Female","Female","Female","Female","Male","Female","Female","Male","Male","Male","Female","Female","Female","Female"))
age <- c(21,25,32,24,63,52,75,24,65,95,58,36,46,58,65,19,47,48,33,54)
education <- factor(c("Primary","Secondary","Secondary","Higher","Secondary","Primary","Higher","Secondary","Secondary","Higher","Secondary","Secondary","Higher","Secondary","Secondary","Primary","Secondary","Higher","Secondary","Secondary"))
df1 <- data.frame(id,sex,age,education)

table <- df1 %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  tbl_summary(statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                               all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
              label = list(sex ~ "Sex",
                           age ~ "Age (years)",
                           education ~ "Educational attainment")) %>% 
  modify_footnote(
    all_stat_cols() ~ "Statistics presented:  \nn (%) for continuous variables;  \nMean (SD) for categorical variables"
  ) %>% 
  as_flex_table() %>% 
  fontsize(size = 8, part = "all") %>% 
  padding(padding.top = 1, part = "all") %>%
  padding(padding.bottom = 1, part = "all")


save_as_docx(
  "Table: Descriptive statistics" = table,
  path = "Table3.docx")
```

With `valign(valign = "center", part = "all")`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
library(flextable)

id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
sex <- factor(c("Male","Female","Female","Male","Female","Male","Female","Female","Female","Female","Male","Female","Female","Male","Male","Male","Female","Female","Female","Female"))
age <- c(21,25,32,24,63,52,75,24,65,95,58,36,46,58,65,19,47,48,33,54)
education <- factor(c("Primary","Secondary","Secondary","Higher","Secondary","Primary","Higher","Secondary","Secondary","Higher","Secondary","Secondary","Higher","Secondary","Secondary","Primary","Secondary","Higher","Secondary","Secondary"))
df1 <- data.frame(id,sex,age,education)

table <- df1 %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  tbl_summary(statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                               all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
              label = list(sex ~ "Sex",
                           age ~ "Age (years)",
                           education ~ "Educational attainment")) %>% 
  modify_footnote(
    all_stat_cols() ~ "Statistics presented:  \nn (%) for continuous variables;  \nMean (SD) for categorical variables"
  ) %>% 
  as_flex_table() %>% 
  fontsize(size = 8, part = "all") %>% 
  padding(padding.top = 1, part = "all") %>%
  padding(padding.bottom = 1, part = "all") %>%  
  valign(valign = "center", part = "all")

save_as_docx(
  "Table: Descriptive statistics" = table,
  path = "Table.docx")
```